# JAX-WS server application cannot start due to schema validation

Tags: java, jax-ws, w3c, mtom

Application can't start with following exception:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
15:19:04.697 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#1' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#e5522a5' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e5522a5': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206) ~[catalina-6.0.37.jar:6.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705) ~[catalina-6.0.37.jar:6.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) ~[catalina-6.0.37.jar:6.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840) ~[catalina-6.0.37.jar:6.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) ~[catalina-6.0.37.jar:6.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) ~[catalina-6.0.37.jar:6.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825) ~[catalina-6.0.37.jar:6.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat6.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:997) ~[tomcat6-maven-plugin-2.2.jar:2.2]
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat6.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:512) ~[tomcat6-maven-plugin-2.2.jar:2.2]
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:298) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105) ~[maven-core-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960) ~[maven-embedder-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293) ~[maven-embedder-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196) ~[maven-embedder-3.8.7.jar:3.8.7]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e5522a5': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.ServerSchemaValidationTube.<init>(ServerSchemaValidationTube.java:70) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ServerTubeAssemblerContext.createValidationTube(ServerTubeAssemblerContext.java:187) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.ValidationTubeFactory.createTube(ValidationTubeFactory.java:34) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:67) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createServer(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:166) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:163) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:307) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:302) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:134) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:578) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:368) ~[jaxws-spring-1.9.jar:?]
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:80) ~[jaxws-spring-1.9.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        ... 48 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:399) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:326) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1466) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1013) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:629) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2180) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:2083) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1013) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1125) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1125) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:609) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:568) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:534) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:253) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.ServerSchemaValidationTube.<init>(ServerSchemaValidationTube.java:68) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ServerTubeAssemblerContext.createValidationTube(ServerTubeAssemblerContext.java:187) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.ValidationTubeFactory.createTube(ValidationTubeFactory.java:34) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:67) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createServer(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:166) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:163) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:307) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:302) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:134) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:578) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:368) ~[jaxws-spring-1.9.jar:?]
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:80) ~[jaxws-spring-1.9.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        ... 48 more
Jan 26, 2023 3:19:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#1' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#e5522a5' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e5522a5': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.Abstract
AutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat6.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:997)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat6.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:512)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:298)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e5522a5': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.ServerSchemaValidationTube.<init>(ServerSchemaValidationTube.java:70)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ServerTubeAssemblerContext.createValidationTube(ServerTubeAssemblerContext.java:187)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.ValidationTubeFactory.createTube(ValidationTubeFactory.java:34)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:67)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createServer(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:166)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:163)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:307)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:302)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:134)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:578)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:368)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:399)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:326)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1466)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1013)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:629)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2180)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:2083)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1013)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1125)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1125)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:624)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:609)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:568)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:534)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:253)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.ServerSchemaValidationTube.<init>(ServerSchemaValidationTube.java:68)
        ... 63 more

Jan 26, 2023 3:19:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Issues started around middle of January 2023 when tried to restart the server.

Seems that issue is caused by the redirect (HTTP 302) from HTTP to HTTPS and application cannot process it.
So probably related to HTTPS redirect (newly done) by w3c.org. More details in:

- https://www.w3.org/blog/2022/07/redirecting-to-https-on-www-w3-org/
- https://www.w3.org/blog/2022/08/https-redirection-observations/

Related to the fact that app is using `@SchemaValidation` (com.sun.xml.ws.developer) and in the WSDL we have element with `type="xs:base64Binary" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"` (due to the MTOM)

Application is using:

- openjdk version "1.8.0_362" (Temurin)
- Apache Tomcat 8.5.78
- jaxws-ri 2.3.5

We were trying to use different JDK to try if there could be difference in SAX parser. But no luck.

Is there please a way how to resolve it? (questions next to linked w3c.org articles remains not answered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution:
It is enough to upgrade jaxws (jaxws-rt or jaxws-ri - depends on your usage).

We upgraded to version 2.3.6 released 6.2.2023:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Didn't find any release notes so far.

- tag - https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/releases/tag/2.3.6
- branch https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/commits/2.3.6-RELEASE